# Accessing results of Angular filter outside of nested repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I've been searching and fiddling with this for about a day now with no luck. I have a site using AngularJS 1.3.6 where I need to get the results of a filter outside of several nested ng-repeats. I'm filtering the rows in several tables, and the filter itself is working fine. But, outside of the tables, I need to get the number of results (if filtering isn't happening, get the total) as well as number of parents included. I'm currently using:

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in (filteredChildren = (parent.children| filter: query))">
```

I can get that outside of the children repeat in the parent repeat. But, I also need a grandparent repeat outside of all of that where it will be referenced. 

[Here is a plunkr illustrating my problem.](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0jwJNCTy3sBYYc4kGJ6?p=preview)

There you can see filteredChildren returns nothing when in the grandparent's repeat, but it does when in the parent's repeat. 

Is it possible to access the filter's results outside of nested ng-repeats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but the key to understanding why lies in understanding in what scope each `filteredChildren` variable lives.

`filteredChildren` is a filtered version of `parent.children` and lives in the same scope. In fact, it is *declared* in that scope - that is the scope inside (i.e. for each iteration of) the "parent" `ng-repeat`. So, in other words, it is defined in the child scope of the "grandparent" `ng-repeat`.

Instead of creating a new variable for a filtered array, create it as an item of the array (with corresponding index of each parent) defined at the grandparent level. Let's say, it will be defined on each `grandparent` variable:

```
<div ng-repeat="grandparent in grandparents">
  <div ng-repeat="parent in grandparent.parents" ng-init="pIdx = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="child in (grandparent.filteredChildren[pIdx] = (parent.children| filter: query))">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, this will create an array of arrays and you would need another function to calculate the total number of children for a grandparent:

```
$scope.sumLength = function(arrayOfArrays){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++){
     var childArray = arrayOfArrays[i];
     if (childArray) sum += childArray.length;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

You could then add it inside "grandparents" `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="grandparent in grandparents" 
     ng-init="grandparent.filteredChildren = []">
  total children: {{sumLength(grandparent.filteredChildren)}}
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I really enjoy your approach, thanks for making it so well thought-out. It looks like `grandparent.filteredChildren` is a multidimensional array, so the length function on that isn't working right now. I'll refactor it, but it looks like this is a great approach.

Comment: @Julie, that doesn't make sense. If you are passing `grandparent.filteredChildren` to `sumLength()`, then it should be an array where each item is an array of filtered children for each parent.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that wasn't right... [If you look in my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0jwJNCTy3sBYYc4kGJ6?p=preview) you'll see I'm getting an error that the array that was passed in is undefined. I'm going to keep working on it but insight would be appreciated

Comment: Oh, I see... `grandparent.filteredChildren` is created as an Object, not an Array. You'd need to initialize it, say with `ng-init`, to `[]`. http://plnkr.co/edit/l0l290DNKnxsbkEgdgVh?p=preview. I updated the answer

Comment: Oh how did I miss that.. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You want to set index for each `filteredParents[$index]` & `filteredChildren[$index]`

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="grandparent in grandparents">
      <div>
        <h2> {{grandparent.name}} has {{filteredParents[$index].length}} <!--??-->  Parents and {{filteredChildren[$index].length}} Children </h2>
      </div>
      <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search for a child">
    <div ng-repeat="parent in ($parent.filteredParents[$index] = (grandparent.parents | filter: query))">
      <h2>{{parent.name}}</h2>
      {{filteredChildren.length}}
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>col1</th>
              <th>col2</th>
              <th>col3</th>
          </tr>  
        </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="child in ($parent.filteredChildren[$parent.$index] = (parent.children | filter: query))">
             <td>{{child.value1}}</td>
             <td>{{child.value2}}</td>
             <td>{{child.value3}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Khv1hpGWaXTFTyjwhh3M?p=info)

Comment: The index definitely helps, thanks for making a plunkr as well. I'll be using a mixture of yours and New Dev's answers, as they helped with the addition piece.